# unshare --map-root-user switch to original uid/username after setup

Tags: linux, users, root, namespace, unshare

I'm using unshare to create per process mounts, which is working perfectly fine by

```
unshare -m --map-root-user
```

However, after having created my bind-mounts by

```
mount --bind src dst
```

I want to change the UID to my original user, so that `whoami` (and others) echoes my username like `echo $USER` does.

I have already tried  the answer of
[Simulate chroot with unshare](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66084/simulate-chroot-with-unshare/303660)

However, doing `su – user1` after `chroot /`, I get

```
su: Authentication failure
(Ignored)
setgid: Invalid argument
```

I have tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 Beta, Debian stretch, openSUSE-Leap-42.3.
It's all the same. I guess something has changed in the kernel since this answer was working.

What is a working and correct way to do that (of course without beeing **real** root)?

Answer (score 7):

The [`unshare(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/unshare.1.en.html) command can't do it:

> -r, --map-root-user
>   [...] As a mere convenience feature, it does not support more sophisticated use cases, such as mapping multiple ranges
>   of UIDs and GIDs.

Supplementary groups if any (`video`, ...) will be lost anyway (or mapped to `nogroup`).

By changing again into a 2nd new user namespace, it's possible to revert back the mapping. This requires a custom program, since `unshare(1)` won't do it. Here's a very minimalistic C program as proof of concept (one user only: uid/gid 1000/1000, zero failure check). Let's call it `revertuid.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;

    unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER);
    fd=open("/proc/self/setgroups",O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"deny",4);
    close(fd);
    fd=open("/proc/self/uid_map",O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"1000 0 1",8);
    close(fd);
    fd=open("/proc/self/gid_map",O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"1000 0 1",8);
    close(fd);
    execvp(argv[1],argv+1);
}
```

It's just doing the reverse mapping of the mapping done by `unshare -r -m`, which was unavoidable, to be able to be root and use `mount`, as seen with:

```
$ strace unshare -r -m /bin/sleep 1 2>&1 |sed -n '/^unshare/,/^execve/p'
unshare(CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWUSER)      = 0
open("/proc/self/setgroups", O_WRONLY)  = 3
write(3, "deny", 4)                     = 4
close(3)                                = 0
open("/proc/self/uid_map", O_WRONLY)    = 3
write(3, "0 1000 1", 8)                 = 8
close(3)                                = 0
open("/proc/self/gid_map", O_WRONLY)    = 3
write(3, "0 1000 1", 8)                 = 8
close(3)                                = 0
execve("/bin/sleep", ["/bin/sleep", "1"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0
```

So that gives:

```
user@stretch-amd64:~$ gcc -o revertuid revertuid.c
user@stretch-amd64:~$ mkdir -p /tmp/src /tmp/dst
user@stretch-amd64:~$ touch /tmp/src/file
user@stretch-amd64:~$ ls /tmp/dst
user@stretch-amd64:~$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)
user@stretch-amd64:~$ unshare -r -m
root@stretch-amd64:~# mount --bind /tmp/src /tmp/dst
root@stretch-amd64:~# ls /tmp/dst
file
root@stretch-amd64:~# exec ./revertuid bash
user@stretch-amd64:~$ ls /tmp/dst
file
user@stretch-amd64:~$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)
```

Or shorter:

```
user@stretch-amd64:~$ unshare -r -m sh -c 'mount --bind /tmp/src /tmp/dst; exec ./revertuid bash'
user@stretch-amd64:~$ ls /tmp/dst
file
```

The behaviour probably changed after kernel 3.19 as seen in [`user_namespaces(7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/user_namespaces.7.en.html#The_/proc/%5Bpid%5D/setgroups_file):

> The */proc/[pid]/setgroups* file was added in Linux 3.19, but was
>   backported to many earlier stable kernel series, because it addresses
>   a security issue. The issue concerned files with permissions such as
>   "rwx---rwx".

Comment: does this work for more complicated cases? I ask because I created a namespace with unshare and used newuidmap to map the user to root with all the other common ids mapped to the ids in /etc/subuid.  I then used revertuid in this namespace and it only seems to work for the user id ("0 1000 1") and not for any of the subuids ("1000 0 1\n0 1 999\n").

Comment: @Compholio newuidmap is a **setuid root** helper tool. This answer was written without accounting for the use of newuidmap or any privileged tool. Without external help from a privileged process, a non privileged (in the host namespace) user can only map between itself (in the current namespace) and one other user (in the new namespace). Only 1000 or 0 are of interest. Today the `unshare` command can do what's in this answer with `--map-user=` and `--map-group=`.

Comment: @Compholio Also user mapping is hierarchical: it's inherited from parent, and can only shrink in size. There's no way to "map back" anything that wasn't mapped in the parent. The initial user namespace has 2^32 uids. If the new created (with the help of newuidmap) has uid 1000 + typically uids 65536-131071 (or 100000-165535) mapped, there's no way to ever map back for example hosts' uid 1001, with or without help of any privileged process (which could grant more than newuidmap but can't anyway).

Comment: I'm not trying to map back to the host ids, I understand that is impossible.  What I would like to be able to do is "drop root" but still retain all the other ids.  So, step 1: make new namespace with user=root, ids 1-1000 from subuid pool; step 2: make root=user, but keep ids 1-1000 rather than map them all to nobody. (ideally I would also like to map, say, 1001 to root)

Comment: I feel like this needs a picture, hopefully this helps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2kjg00zi8td7q5/example.png?dl=0

Comment: Interestingly, I can get this to work like I expect from the parent process by echoing the desired mapping to `/proc/$ID/uid_map` instead of using `/proc/self/uid_map` in the child process or doing the same with the custom "revertuid".

Answer (score 0):

Note: as bwrap is available in more places than util-linux > 2.39.1 right now, [this answer using bwrap](https://superuser.com/a/1592795/638934) is probably worth consideration for systems prior to Ubuntu 23.10. (On the other hand, this solution propagates ^C properly and bwrap doesn't)

However unlike bwrap, this solution based on unshare, properly propagates ^C for interactive CLI invocations.

You can't *change* the UID but with modern util-linux you can start off as non-root and then use `nsenter` to get root and make the mount.

It is necessary to start the names-space with unshare, wait until it is ready, perform some mounts as fake-root, and when the mounts are ready, let the namespace run its tasks.

This takes two lots of synchronization, to wait until the namespace is ready before performing mounts, and to wait until mounts are ready before running the process.

use as:

```
in-unshare [bind-mount] ... [--] command [arg] ...
```

e.g.

```
in-unshare /build-dir=$PWD/build -- make build

# **Note:** this avoids an implicit exec with: `"$@" ; exit $?` which is necessary for proper signal propagation on ^C
# Who would have thought an extra waiting process layer would be so useful?
in-unshare() (
  local session session_pid mounts
  while test $# != 0
  do case "$1" in
     *=*) mounts+=("$1") ; shift ;;
     --) shift ; break ;;
     *) break;
     esac
  done

  coproc mounter {
    # session_pid will be the same as PPID but we need to wait until namespaces are setup
    read -r session_pid || return $?
    exec 0<&-

    # mount as "root" via nsenter
    for mount in "${mounts[@]}"
    do # quit on error without writing to stdout
       nsenter -U -m --target $session_pid mount "${mount#*=}" "${mount%=*}" -o rbind || return $?
    done
    # signal that mounts are setup
    echo $?
  }

  exec {out}>>/dev/fd/${mounter[1]} {in}</dev/fd/${mounter[0]}
  # note avoiding implict exec with "$@" ; exit $? is neccessary for proper signal shutdown on ^C
  # who would have thought an extra waiting process layer would be so useful
  exec unshare --mount --user --map-user=$(id -u) --map-group=$(id -g) --map-users=auto --map-groups=auto --keep-caps --setgroups allow /bin/bash --noprofile --norc -c "echo \$\$ >&${out} && exec ${out}>&- || exit \$? ; read -u ${in} && exec ${in}<&- && \"\$@\" ; exit $?" unshare "$@"
  exit $?
)
```