# Running su inside mount namespace

Tags: mount, su, namespace

I am testing mount namespace using the following steps:

```
# unshare --mount
# mount --bind rootfs/ ns_dir/
# cd ns_dir/
# pivot_root . .
# cd /
```

My rootfs has sub-folders `/lib`, `/bin`, `/etc`. I have put dependencies for
various binaries including `bash` and `su`.

My question relates to the use of `su` inside the namespace. I tried the following:

```
root:/# su alice
alice:/$ su bob
su: must be run from a terminal
```

I want to ask the meaning of the error `su: must be run from a terminal`. I searched online and find hackish answers like at this [link](https://evertpot.com/189/) which asks to the following:

```
echo "import pty; pty.spawn('/bin/bash')" > /tmp/asdf.py
python /tmp/asdf.py
```

I tried the approach in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/544328/su-must-be-run-from-a-terminal) answer, but it didn't work.
I want to ask what is the right way to resolve this error. I presume the error is occurring because a password needs to be entered to switch the user.

Comment: `pivot_root . .` looks weird to me. Could you explain where do you want to mount the original `/`?

Comment: Inside the mount namespace, I want `ns_dir` to eventually become root. I don't want to mount the original / anywhere. This is how LXC uses `pivot_root`: https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/src/lxc/conf.c#L1516

Comment: I think the original terminal is unreacheable in the namespace. You'd have to bind mount the original /dev/pts/ there. That doesn't mean it's the right way (security issues), just an observation. As a parallel, this happens with LXC and lxc-attach. lxc-console handles it, perhaps like the python command.

Comment: @A.B If you could reference any code for `lxc-console` that handles this, then that would be very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is unshare with non-root inside and then use enterns without the `--preserve-credentials` which gives you root inside the container with which you can do the mounts.

See answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767296/139357 which will be improved upon