# How to mount a local directory without root

Tags: mount, non-root-user, fuse

Say I have a folder which is completely readable by my user. I want it to be mounted to my home folder. I can't use a symlink because I want the files to be exposed at `~/` and I want other programs "not to know" that it's a mount. Is there a fuse program that implements this? The issue with `mount` is that it requires root privileges.

I'd also appreciate, if I'd be able to mount this directory, not on boot, but on demand - that's because my `~/` is encrypted unless I'm logged in.

Comment: `fstab` can have a 'user' option specified on a particular mount. If you set this up once, you can then mount/unmount without being root. Is this an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: @Haxiel the answer I already got seems mostly satisfying, but your alternative seems interesting but I'm not sure I fully understand it although I read the relevant manpages. I tried to do something but I got errors on boot. Would it be possible to get an full answer with an fstab entry example?

Comment: @Haxiel I've also edited the question - I'd like to mount this directory on demand and not on boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up /etc/fstab once, with the following entry:

```
/path/to/original/dir  /path/to/bind/dir  none  bind,rw,user,noauto  0 0
```

The mount options specify the following things, in order:

- `bind` indicates that this entry is a bind mount.
- `rw` specifies that the entry will be mounted in read-write mode.
- `user` allows any non-root user to mount the filesystem.
- `noauto` specifies that this entry should not be automatically mounted with `mount -a` and at boot time.

You'll need to set this up once using root privileges. Once the entry is in place, you can perform the mount as a non-root user. Simply run `mount /path/to/bind/dir`.

A couple of points to note:

- With the `user` option, only the same user account that originally mounted the filesystem can perform the unmount. If multiple users are involved, you can look at the `users` option instead. See `man 8 mount` for details.
- The `user` option implies three other options: `noexec` (do not permit execution of binaries), `nosuid` (do not honor setuid/setgid bits) and `nodev` (do not interpret devices). If you want to restore any of these functionality, append the corresponding option to the end of the list. For example, `bind,rw,user,noauto,exec`. Keep in mind that there are security implications for these options. See `man 8 mount` for details.

Comment: that sounds great but I'm getting this error when I mount without root: `mount: /home/doron/repos: must be superuser to use mount.`. I've added this line to my fstab: `/var/src /home/doron/repos none bind,rw,user,noauto 0 0`.

Comment: @DoronBehar That's a bit strange, because the configuration works on my Fedora system. Can you check if you have more than one entry for '/home/doron/repos' in the `fstab` file?

Comment: Definitely it is the only line with `/var/src` and `/home/doron/repos`. I've also tried to test whether it'll work only if `/var/src` has my _full_ permissions, and I'm the owner of, and that didn't work either, failing the same way :/.

Comment: Is it possible that you have modified the permissions on the `mount` binary itself? I found a discussion [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/must-be-superuser-to-use-mount-fstab-is-correct-however-144932/) that may be helpful.

Comment: It worked! Thanks again @Haxiel for the dedication, deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Various FUSE utilities can do that. For instance, [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) can mount a directory to a different location, similarly to what `mount --bind` would do.

```
bindfs --no-allow-other /source/directory /mount/point
```

The `--no-allow-other` option is needed unless you uncomment `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf` (but see, below, the note about libfuse for the security implications).

Unmount with:

```
fusermount -u /mount/point
```

Note that FUSE file systems currently have known issues/limitations. It's worth mentioning, among other things, the performance cost, the
impossibillity to use [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to monitor file system events occurring on the source file system and the security implications listed in the [libfuse GitHub repository](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse)'s README.

On Linux, a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/315749) performed as `mount --bind` would not have these downsides. But it would require root privileges at least once, to edit your `fstab`.
Refer to the linked Q/A for a *much* more detailed coverage of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767296/139357 which shows how to do bind mounts as non-root using unshare and nsenter

That answer will be improved upon.