# How can I give users read only mount access to ext3 image files?

Tags: mount, sudo

I would like users to be able to mount `ext3` image files as a loop back devices in read only and no execution modes without having to invoke `sudo`.  The `sudo` command currently used is something like:

```
$ EXT3_DIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/ext3-mnt-XXX) ; sudo mount -o loop,ro,user rootfs.ext3 ${EXT3_DIR} && cd ${EXT3_DIR}
```

With that (and `visudo`), I created a file: `/etc/sudoers.d/ext3-ro-mount` with the contents:

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -o loop\,ro\,user *.ext3 /tmp/ext-mnt-*
```

But when I run the mount command without `sudo` elevation, I get the error:

```
mount: only root can use "--options" option
```

*How can I achieve this for users?* (and what would the subsequent `/etc/sudoers.d/ext3-ro-umount` conent look like?)

**EDIT:**

Having misunderstood how what I was doing is actually meant to work, I ran the command *with `sudo`* on a less privileged account, entered the password and got this error:

```
{such and such} is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

*How do I add a user to the sudoers file without making them a full blown sudoer?*  Is this achieved by creating a new group and give the group permission to do this?

**EDIT 2:**

I figured out the issue I was having.  See my answer below.

Comment: I had written an answer for [this QA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/602496/173368) a while back, and it seems similar to your situation. In essence, the process involves setting up an fstab entry with the user/users option. Can you take a look and see if it helps?

Comment: @Haxiel Can the fstab take wildcards? My example shows the image file being `rootfs.ext3`, but in reality, only the suffix (`.ext3`) will be fixed.

Comment: Why is it a problem for the users having to type the extra word `sudo` in front of the mount command?

Comment: @Jamie fstab entries are typically one-to-one mappings of a device/filesystem to a path. So as far as I know, fstab does not support wildcards. You'll need one entry per image file.

Comment: @Haxiel I thought as much, which is why I'm hoping I can do this with a sudo configuration.

Comment: @meuh Asking a user to add `sudo` to the command isn't the issue: I don't want them to have `sudo` privileges, just the ability to mount/umount an image with the restrictions I outlined.

Comment: They will *only* be able to execute the single mount command you have specified, unless you also add them to, say, group `sudo` and you already have a default entry for `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, as some distributions do (or `%wheel` for Fedora). You don't *have* to do that.

Comment: @Jamie After reading question and comments it seems like you are expecting that adding a command to the sudoers configuration allowed a user to run it without `sudo`. It is the other way round: it allows the user to run that command line (and only that one) using `sudo`, while `sudo any other command` will fail.

Comment: @fra-san  You're quite correct.  Let me try logging off and on again to see if what I tried worked.

Comment: Note: You used `-o loop\,ro\,noexec` in the file. A command must contain `-o loop,ro,noexec` to match this. Your command contains `-o loop,noexec,ro`. `sudo` neither is aware nor cares if these are equivalent for `mount`, it compares character strings.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You're quite right, and I knew that.  That was a transcription between console and webUI error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form of the sudoer file I was looking for was to replace `user` with `ALL`:

```
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -o loop\,ro\,user *.ext3 /tmp/ext-mnt-*
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` supports fine grain privileges.

e.g. You can set up so that a specified user or group can execute a specified command with specified arguments with or without a password.

See `man sudoers`

Comment: Do you somehow think the attempt I made was accomplished without consulting documentation? I'm having trouble with the syntax, so obviously, I'm missing something you clearly think is obvious on the man page.  A little more insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You said without `sudo`, therefore I have not given any detail on how to use `sudo`. Only guidance to say that I believe that you should use it. It may now be a good idea after reading the manual, and trying it, to ask another question.